# FFmpeg slideshow with images of different dimensions

Tags: ffmpeg, images, video-editing, slideshow

I have .jpg files like (img001.jpg), each of them with different dimensions. I also have an audio file .ogg. I wanna create slideshow with audio but I have a scaling problem, because the image dimensions are different.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/2 -i img%03d.jpg -i example.ogg -s 1920x1080 AL_SlideShow.mkv
```

(2 second image change interval, x265 1920*1080)

And sound only plays last 30 second I think.

Answer (score 2):

You have to scale the images to a common size. Add a `scale` video filter:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/2 -i img%03d.jpg -i example.ogg \
-vf "scale=1920:1080,format=yuv420p" \
AL_SlideShow.mkv
```

If you want to use `libx265`, you need to specify `-c:v libx265` as well.

You may want to add `-shortest` before the output filename to stop the encoding when all images have been read. That way, the audio stream will be cut.